# NOT+IN SAS operators combined, is this valid? Can't find documentation

Tags: sas, operators

I'm trying to understand how to code something along the lines of "NOT IN the LIST" type of logic in SAS.
I figured I could do "NOT" + "IN" as something like below.

```
Data work.OUT;
 Set work.IN;

    If VAR=1 then OUTPUT=1;
    else if VAR=2 then OUTPUT=2;
    else if VAR NOT in (1,2) then OUTPUT=3;
    else OUTPUT=4;
    run;
```

When I export the dataset all I see is OUTPUT=3 for all records. So something is happening in the derivation and it's transforming all VAR values into OUTPUT 3 values for some reason. Even though I know for a fact that other values exist in the VAR.

I don't understand what the problem is? Can we not combine NOT+IN operators? Alternatively, do you have any other ways of coding this type of logic in SAS? I rather not code each bit of code since I have more than 300 unique values for VAR

Comment: Please show a proc freq of the output comparing VAR to output. `proc freq data=out; table var*output; run;` OUTPUT is a key work so that may also be causing issues. Try using a different variable name to make it clear. Your third clause will capture everything except 1/2 so the last ELSE won't ever be valid though.

Comment: Usage of not in is perfectly correct and valid, the issue is elsewhere. Possibly rounding as well.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Alejandro. Your code assigns values 1 2 or 3 depending on what values are in the variable called var:

```
data in;
    do var = 1 to 5;
    output;
    end;
run;

Data work.OUT;
    set work.IN;

    If VAR=1 then OUTPUT=1;
    else if VAR=2 then OUTPUT=2;
    else if VAR NOT in (1,2) then OUTPUT=3;
    else OUTPUT=4;
run;
```

Your code says check for var = 1 then check for var = 2 and then check if it is not 1 or 2. The final else is never checked because a var will be 1 or 2 or not 1 or 2.

If you have a pile of if checks, you can use a select/when/otherwise/end block.  It will check a series of rules (in the order you type them) and then will do something based on whichever rule is true first.

```
data out;
    set in;
    select;
        when(var = 1) output = 1;
        when(var = 2) output = 2;
        when(var < 5) output = 3;
        when(.) output = -9999999;
        otherwise output = 42;
    end;
run;
```

I hope that helps.  If not please send up another flare.